# Docacl Output Property in Content Enrichment Sharepoint Search 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

We are attempting to output a docacl via a content enrichment service in SharePoint Search 2013.  I have linked the managed property to a crawl property and am trying to register as such:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$config = New-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration
$config.Endpoint = "[url to enrichment service]"
$config.InputProperties = "Location", "OriginalPath"
$config.OutputProperties = "Location", "docaclmeta"
$config.SendRawData = $False
$config.MaxRawDataSize = 8192

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchContentEnrichmentConfiguration –SearchApplication $ssa –ContentEnrichmentConfiguration $config
```

Everything seemed to be working fine until the introduction of "docaclmeta" as an output property.  I'm getting the following error in the log:

> Error Category: InvalidArgument    Target Object 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]  Details  NULL 
>   RecommendedAction NULL

Any help with getting this output property working will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I need to set docaclmeta in cews as well bu I get the same error as you.